# Removing rows based off of a value in a column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, row, dataframe

I'm trying to remove row values if the column 'Comment' has 'Bad Process' in it.

```
    ID Name         Comment
0     W12D0           Fine
1     W12D0    Bad Process
2     W12D0           What
3     W12D4           Fine
4     W12D5         Random
5     W12D5           Fine
..      ...            ...
```

Notice how the ID Name '**W12D0**' has 3 comments: *Fine, Bad Process, What*. Because that ID Name has 'Bad Process' corresponding to it, I want to remove all occurrences of W12D0. Essentially I'm looking for data that looks like this (w/ reindexing):

```
    ID Name         Comment
1     W12D4           Fine
2     W12D5         Random
3     W12D5           Fine
..      ...            ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.loc` to get the `ID Name` of all rows which have 'Bad Process' in the Comments column.

You then use `.loc` again, but this time as a mask to filter out the bad records.  The tilda (~) is a negation, so it finds rows in the dataframe where the ID Name is NOT in the list of bad records.

```
bad = df.loc[df.Comment.str.contains('Bad Process'), 'ID Name']
df_good = df.loc[~df['ID Name'].isin(bad)]

>>> df_good
  ID Name Comment
3   W12D4    Fine
4   W12D5  Random
5   W12D5    Fine
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

First identofy the bad rows:

`bad_rows = df[df.Comment == 'Bad Process'].Name`

Then delete them from the data frame:

`df[-df.Name.isin(bad_rows)]`